# chrome extension - reading first bytes of crdownload file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to Write a chrome extension, that when a user start download a file, it will read the first bytes of the crdownload file (temporary file in proccess of downloading), to get it's magic number.

In my current code, i could get the mime type, but not read from the crdownload file:

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, __suggest) {
    console.log(item.mime);
});
```

Comment: Extensions can't read arbitrary files unless the user explicitly allows the access in chrome://extensions and your extension had the corresponding permissions in manifest.json, like `<all_urls>`. When both conditions are satisfied, you can use XMLHttpRequest or fetch() to perform a range request on a file:// url.